# Exporting blender model to Indesign

Tags: export, makehuman

I create different poses in blender with my character, that I made with makehuman. I want to export this character to Indesign for a workoutmanual. 
When I export the character (to meshlab for example) the poses are gone an the character is silver, so it doesen´t wear the clothes that I put on in makehuman.

Any ideas?

Comment: this question is not about blender... anyway you didn't explain what you did exactly, anyway.

Comment: Indesign is an illustration and layout 2D application, as far as I know there is no way to export 3D models directly. You either have to render them or capture in a 2D image or vector format.